Python Dash: How to add HTML code gernerated during a callback to the layout?
My current specific problem is that I would like to render a pandas DataFrame that is generated during a callback as table. It does not have to be clickable, sortable, etc.
Currently I am using markdown as an intermediate representation:
import dash
from dash import html, dcc
from dash.dependencies import Input, Output
import pandas as pd

app = dash.Dash(__name__)
app.layout = html.Div(
    [
        html.Button("Show table", id="button"),
        html.Div(children="Table should show up here", id="table-output"),
    ]
)

@app.callback(
    Output("table-output", "children"),
    Input("button", "n_clicks"),
    prevent_initial_call=True
)
def show_table(n_clicks):
    df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3],[2, 3, 4]], columns=['a', 'b', 'c'])
   
    return [html.Div([dcc.Markdown(children=df.to_markdown())])]

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run_server(debug=True)

I know about the DataTable, which I used in another occasion. It would certainly solve the problem, but it seems to be "over engineered" in this case. Since DataFrame has a to_html() method, I expected there would be a simpler way. I am interested in both, the specific case (i.e. using pandas DataFrame) and the general case (i.e. HTML code generated by Python).
Update: I tried the suggestion provided by @winter and this can improve style and feels less like a workaround. However, it solves only the specific case when dealing with tables and DataFrame. For the generic solution, I was looking for something like an "inline expansion", some way that HTML code can be passed directly to the app.

You can use dash bootstrap table for this, it supports displaying dataframes out of the box and easy to use. You can check out this here for more details under section Table from DataFrame
